# pair two rows together in sql oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a below table structure

[image]

When the agreement type for the employee  is Basic and Appendix (e.g. row 1,2 & 5,6) then these two rows need to be considered together and status would be active. Below should be the expected outcome

[image]

How can this be achieved in oracle 10g. Thanks

Comment: select emp_id, agreement_type as status from your_table where agreement_type in ('Basic', 'Appendix')

Comment: Where did `Pending` come from?

Comment: @Oguen - Have you noticed the expected outcome?

Comment: This is a really high risk design. You are almost inevitably going to get errors. You need an extra column that groups the rows. Eg Basic and Appendix belong to negotiation_id 1, the next belongs to negotiation_id 2 etc. this way you can see which records are associated. You can then execute the grouping with ease

Comment: well, jepg incomes lead unnoticed outcomes i guess. I thought Deepak's data sample just randomly filled excel cells.

Comment: So for rows which cannot be paired e.g. 3, 4 the status would be Pending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using a `CASE` statement and the `LEAD` analytic function to see if the next ID is **Appendix**.

### Query

```sql
--This is to set up the sample data
WITH
    emp_agreements (id, emp_id, agreement_type)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, 1023, 'Basic' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 2, 1023, 'Appendix' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, 1023, 'Basic' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 1023, 'Basic' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 5, 1023, 'Basic' FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 6, 1023, 'Appendix' FROM DUAL)
--Real query begins here. You will need to put in your real table name
  SELECT emp_id, status
    FROM (SELECT id,
                 emp_id,
                 agreement_type,
                 CASE LEAD (agreement_type) OVER (PARTITION BY emp_id ORDER BY id)
                     WHEN 'Appendix' THEN 'Active'
                     ELSE 'Pending'
                 END    AS status
            FROM emp_agreements)
   WHERE agreement_type = 'Basic'
ORDER BY id;
```

### Result

```
   EMP_ID     STATUS
_________ __________
     1023 Active
     1023 Pending
     1023 Pending
     1023 Active
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted. I never thought I would use LEAD.